# Enable continuous scrolling when scrolling using arrow keys while generating PDF file through java itext api (com.lowagie.text.pdf)

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have a java class for generating PDF using itext api (com.lowagie.text.pdf). In Adobe reader, in 'View' tab, when you select 'Page Display' option, there you have one option 'Enable Scrolling'. If we enable this option, then we can scroll the PDF file using arrow keys continuously otherwise as we scroll using the arrow keys, scroll stops at the end of each page. I need to enable this option while generating PDF file using the java api specified above.

Anyone having any idea about it please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited number of preferences available called the Viewer Preferences (cp [pdf spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) page 362) Those options specify how conforming readers should behave. However as you can see yourself there is no option regarding scrolling. Thus it seems that setting the option in your reader is the only option...

Comment: Actually I was setting page layout as single page using below code snippet:                                                                     pdfWriter.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage);                                                                          By removing this page layout option I was able to enable continuous scrolling for the PDF files generating.                                                           Anyways, thanks for your answer